# In Vs On Vs At (when talking about streets)

Tags: grammar

I have found many sentences with street names and some of them have these three prepositions. I Don't know, but I believe that Americans use (on + name of the street) and British use (in + name of the street). So if I am correct about this, are these sentences correct?

> He lives in Oxford St.
>
> He lives on Oxford St.

I also came across that "in" is not used when we want to talk about exact location, you'd use "at" instead. So, are these sentences correct?

> He lives at 4732 Marshall Drive.
>
> Alice's office is at 26515 Main Street.

These last two sentences I've come across them using the prepositon "on", but if "at" is used to exact location, I think that "on" would be incorrect. I don't know if there is any difference between British and American English in this case.

Comment: I think we have questions on this already, but I can’t find them right off the bat.

Answer (score 3):

In British English, the name of the street without any further precision is preceded by *in* when you’re talking about where someone lives: *he lives in Oxford Street*. The precise address is preceded by *at*: *he lives at 128 Oxford Street*. *On* may occasionally be found to say where a building is located: *Ikea have a big new store on Oxford Street*.